# AWS MediaLive MediaPackage - How to store realtime streaming videos to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I'm using AWS MediaLive to push video content in real-time from mobile devices.
Then I'm using AWS MediaPackage to digest the input, i.e. the output from AWS MediaLive.
With AWS MediaLive I create origin endpoints to let users/viewers watch live streamings.

Now, I don't know how to store the live streaming video to S3 and distribute it through a CDN, in order to let watching the video even once the streaming is ended.
Is something provided by AWS out-of-the-box?

**Update**:

I defined an `ArchiveGroupSettings` with output URL to an S3 bucket.
Now MediaLive creates `.ts` files and sends them to the bucket, the problem is that `.ts` files don't include a `.m3u8` playlist file.

Should I use another AWS Media service?
What I need it's just a way to stream videos once the realtime stream is finished, i.e. to save the HLS video to S3 or similar, then distribute it through a CDN like CloudFront.

NOTE:
I'm using the AWS MediaLive and MediaPackage APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to create another output it's HLS output group and setup destination to MediaStore.

> AWS Elemental MediaStore is an AWS storage service optimized for
>   media. It gives you the performance, consistency, and low latency
>   required to deliver live streaming video content. AWS Elemental
>   MediaStore acts as the origin store in your video workflow. Its high
>   performance capabilities meet the needs of the most demanding media
>   delivery workloads, combined with long-term, cost-effective storage.

To have a whole record of your video you have to set up configuration in `Manifest and Segments` section of your HLS Output group:

```
Output Selection: "MANIFESTS_AND_SEGMENTS"
Mode: "VOD"
```

**Update:**
I recommended you to use MediaStore instead of S3 because MediaStore is the service based on S3 and have the same price that S3. And it's dedicated to working with media files.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Yours his a good solution, but doesn't reply to my question.

Comment: Hi! I would like to ask you did you reply to your question? :)
The only difference is that you use S3 instead of MediaStore and the main configuration is the same that my answer has.
Nevertheless, I'm glad that you find your solution in a minute after my reply.

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr Yarushevskyi, I forgot to add my reply but I got this solution from the AWS forum few weeks ago. But you are right, the only difference is using S3 instead of MediaStore

Comment: This information is incorrect. MediaStore is not based on S3. S3 is not suitable for live HLS streams because it doesn't have read-after-write consistency. This means that updates to the m3u8 playlist won't be visible quickly enough. At the same time, S3 is cheaper and better suited to VOD (ie, non-live) delivery than MediaStore. Eg, S3 supports Transfer Acceleration, which is like a CDN but cheaper and easier when there's few viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved, using `HlsGroupSettings`, instead of  `ArchiveGroupSettings`, with destinations URLs to the S3 bucket with `VOD` mode instead of `LIVE`.